# Will a SVN for multiple terabytes of graphics/images require a large amount of space for the repository?

Tags: images, svn, version-control

I am looking at implementing a simple SVN for our design department.   I am leaning towards SVN with Versions (OS X client).

We have about 3 TB and growing of design images.

I'm curious how SVN handles large image files, and a very large amount of them.

Comment: I'm going to try a test with some data that is mirrored from the working directory and see how much it grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will require a large amount of space.

It just stores them as blobs of data. There will be no diffs created for them. It will continue to grow every time a file is committed.

Answer (score 0):

It will obviously take a good bit of space, considering you have terabytes of data. Storing the revisions will expand rather quickly, considering SVN doesn't have the best binary diff system.

I would look into a version control system that does offer strong binary difference tracking (can't think of any off the top of my head, sorry), and see if that can save you some time and space.

In general, you probably can make SVN work for this, at the cost of a good bit of space. Performance depends on how many files you're working with, also.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if content is already in compressed format or not. Subversion uses zlib compression, so repository itself may require less space than working copy if most of it compressable at decent ratio.